# How to convert list of numpy arrays into single numpy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Suppose I have ;

```
LIST = [[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1,2,3,4,5])] # inner lists are numpy arrays
```

I try to convert;

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I am solving it by iteration on vstack right now but it is really slow for especially large LIST

What do you suggest for the best efficient way?

Comment: `LIST = [[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1,2,3,4,5])]` this is not correct python syntax. Please clarify.

Comment: even the compiler is less rude

Comment: OP specified numpy in the title; `array` is one of the common objects in that framework. If OP did `from numpy import array` it'd be correct. Agreed with the above comment from Hedwin, there's no reason to be mean to the OP just because the question requires a little knowledge about a part of the Python ecosystem that's practically part of the standard library.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

In general you can concatenate a whole sequence of arrays along any axis:

```
numpy.concatenate( LIST, axis=0 )
```

but you **do** have to worry about the shape and dimensionality of each array in the list (for a 2-dimensional 3x5 output, you need to ensure that they are all 2-dimensional n-by-5 arrays already).   If you want to concatenate 1-dimensional arrays as the rows of a 2-dimensional output, you need to expand their dimensionality.

As Jorge's answer points out, there is also the function `stack`, introduced in numpy 1.10:

```
numpy.stack( LIST, axis=0 )
```

This takes the complementary approach: it creates a new view of each input array and adds an extra dimension (in this case, on the left, so each `n`-element 1D array becomes a 1-by-`n` 2D array) before concatenating. It will only work if all the input arrays have the same shape.

`vstack` (or equivalently `row_stack`) is often an easier-to-use solution because it will take a sequence of 1- and/or 2-dimensional arrays and expand the dimensionality automatically where necessary and only where necessary, before concatenating the whole list together. Where a new dimension is required, it is added on the left. Again, you can concatenate a whole list at once without needing to iterate:

```
numpy.vstack( LIST )
```

This flexible behavior is also exhibited by the syntactic shortcut `numpy.r_[ array1, ...., arrayN ]` (note the square brackets).  This is good for concatenating a few explicitly-named arrays but it becomes less readable in your situation because `[]` subscripting will not accept a `list`. You would need to convert your sequence to a `tuple`:   `numpy.r_[tuple(LIST)]`.   It's more readable to simply use `vstack()`.

There is also an analogous function `column_stack` and shortcut `c_[...]`, for horizontal (column-wise) stacking, as well as an *almost*-analogous function `hstack`—although for some reason the latter is less flexible (it is stricter about input arrays' dimensionality, and tries to concatenate 1-D arrays end-to-end instead of treating them as columns).

Finally, in the specific case of vertical stacking of 1-D arrays, the following also works:

```
numpy.array( LIST )
```

...because arrays can be constructed out of a sequence of other arrays, adding a new dimension to the beginning.

Comment: I think he wanted a 2d array as output.

Comment: This answer ist not correct.
np.concatenate(LIST, axis=0) will result in a 1D-array. This answer should not be the accepted one

Comment: @svebert read the rest of it?

Answer (score 17):

Starting in NumPy version 1.10, we have the method [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack). It can stack arrays of any dimension (all equal):

```
# List of arrays.
L = [np.random.randn(5,4,2,5,1,2) for i in range(10)]

# Stack them using axis=0.
M = np.stack(L)
M.shape # == (10,5,4,2,5,1,2)
np.all(M == L) # == True

M = np.stack(L, axis=1)
M.shape # == (5,10,4,2,5,1,2)
np.all(M == L) # == False (Don't Panic)

# This are all true    
np.all(M[:,0,:] == L[0]) # == True
all(np.all(M[:,i,:] == L[i]) for i in range(10)) # == True
```

Enjoy,

Answer (score 15):

I checked some of the methods for speed performance and find that **there is no difference!**
The only difference is that using some methods you must carefully check dimension.

Timing:

```
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
|            | shape (10000)  |  shape (1,10000)  |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
| np.concat  |    0.18280     |      0.17960      |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
|  np.stack  |    0.21501     |      0.16465      |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
| np.vstack  |    0.21501     |      0.17181      |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
|  np.array  |    0.21656     |      0.16833      |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
```

As you can see I tried 2 experiments - using `np.random.rand(10000)` and `np.random.rand(1, 10000)`
And if we use 2d arrays than `np.stack` and `np.array` create additional dimension - result.shape is (1,10000,10000) and (10000,1,10000) so they need additional actions to avoid this.

Code:

```
from time import perf_counter
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
import numpy as np
l = []
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(10000)):
    new_np = np.random.rand(10000)
    l.append(new_np)



start = perf_counter()
stack = np.stack(l, axis=0 )
print(f'np.stack: {perf_counter() - start:.5f}')

start = perf_counter()
vstack = np.vstack(l)
print(f'np.vstack: {perf_counter() - start:.5f}')

start = perf_counter()
wrap = np.array(l)
print(f'np.array: {perf_counter() - start:.5f}')

start = perf_counter()
l = [el.reshape(1,-1) for el in l]
conc = np.concatenate(l, axis=0 )
print(f'np.concatenate: {perf_counter() - start:.5f}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Other solution is to use the `asarray` function:

> numpy.asarray( LIST )

Answer (score 0):

I found a much more robust numpy function `reshape`.

Problem of `stack` and `vstack` is, that it fails for an empty list.

```
>>> LIST = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),np.array([1,2,3,4,5])]
>>> s = np.vstack(LIST)
>>> s.shape
(3, 5)
>>> s = np.vstack([])
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

The alternative is reshape

```
>>> s = np.reshape(LIST, (len(LIST),5))
>>> s.shape
(3, 5)
>>> LIST = []
>>> s = np.reshape(LIST, (len(LIST),5))
>>> s.shape
(0,5)
```

Drawback is, you need to know the length/shape of your inner array