# Convert a list of numpy arrays to a 5D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am having a database of 7000 objects (list_of_objects), each one of these files contains a numpy array with size of `10x5x50x50x3`. I would like to create a 5d numpy array that will contain `7000*10x5x50x50x3`. I tried to do so using two for-loops. My sample code:

```
fnl_lst = []
for object in list_of_objects:
     my_array = read_array(object) # size 10x5x50x50x3
     for ind in my_array:
        fnl_lst.append(ind)
fnl_lst= np.asarray( fnl_lst) # print(fnl_lst) -> (70000,)
```

That code result in the end in a nested numpy array which contains 70000 arrays each of them has a size of `5x50x50x3`. However, I would like instead to build a 5d array with size `70000x5x50x50x3`. How can I do that instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of numpy arrays into single numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array)

Comment: Are you sure all the `ind` are the same shape?  What does `np.vstack([read_array(o) for o in list_of_objects])` produce?

Comment: @hpaulj I will cross-check. Maybe that is my issue that the ind for some reason do not have the same size.

Comment: What is `fnl_lst.dtype`?  If `object`, then yes, there's some variation in the shapes.

Comment: True one files have different size and could not monitor it. Now it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fnl_lst = np.stack([ind for ind in read_array(obj) for obj in list_of_objects])
```

or, just append to the existing code:

```
fnl_lst = np.stack(fnl_lst)
```

**UPD:** by hpaulj's comment, if `my_array` is indeed 10x5x50x50x3, this might be enough:

```
fnl_lst = np.stack([read_array(obj) for obj in list_of_objects])
```