# How to extract tuples from sublists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have tried many ways to solve this but instead of getting the tuples, I get individual elements like
'[' , '(' ,'a'.

```
 My input:[[('a','b')],[('b','c'),('d','e')]]

 Required output:('a','b')
                 ('b','c')('d','e')
```

Is there any method to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried before? Show us your code.

Comment: what do you mean by "output". Do you want to print every tuple or create a list containing every tuple?

Comment: Your issue is that you're trying to flatten lists but **not** tuples. Which is a reasonable thing to want, all things considered, but they're both sequences and usually "flatten" functions don't differentiate between tuples and lists (this is a consequence of duck-typing).

Comment: Does this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array

Comment: are you using 'input()' to pass the input? Show minimal example of how does your code currently works.

Comment: res_list = [item for my_list in zip_longest(*input) 
                           for item in my_list if item]                                                   print(res_list)

Answer (score 1):

You can try unpacking:

```
>>> inp = [[('a','b')],[('b','c'),('d','e')]]

>>> for inner_list in inp:
...     print(*inner_list, sep='')

('a', 'b')
('b', 'c')('d', 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

with list comprenhension indexing two times.

```
out = [tup for l in myList for tup in l]
```

you get:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]
```

if you want to print each tupla individually just:

```
for i in out: print(i)
```