# Converting binary classification to multi label?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, classification

> **I am trying to convert my binary image classification model to multilabel and I have been getting errors with NumPy array saying it
>   expects values 2-dimensional values can anyone help me edit the
>   code.**

I tried using multilabelBinazier but I had no luck with that can anyone here help me with that?

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIDl6.png)# USAGE

```
# python train.py --dataset dataset

# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 40
BS = 66

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('/content/drive/My Drive/testset/'))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the image, swap color channels, and resize it to be a fixed
    # 224x224 pixels while ignoring aspect ratio
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
# intensities to the range [0, 255]
data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# initialize the training data augmentation object
trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the VGG16 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are left
# off
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# compute the confusion matrix and and use it to derive the raw
# accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
cm = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs)
total = sum(sum(cm))
acc = (cm[0, 0] + cm[1, 1]) / total
sensitivity = cm[0, 0] / (cm[0, 0] + cm[0, 1])
specificity = cm[1, 1] / (cm[1, 0] + cm[1, 1])

# show the confusion matrix, accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
print(cm)
print("acc: {:.4f}".format(acc))
print("sensitivity: {:.4f}".format(sensitivity))
print("specificity: {:.4f}".format(specificity))

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on COVID-19 Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig("plot.png")

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving COVID-19 detector model...")
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/setcovid/model.h5', )
```

Comment: What do you want to do?
Your loss is still binary_crossentropy so do you want to predict 2 classes?

My initial guess is that your label is not the right shape. Say you have 4 classes, don't you want the first label to be [0,1,0,0] if it is second class?

Answer (score 3):

**Depends on how you preprocess your labels**
There are three points
1. **First one: label shape**
Observe your label shape. From your code I am guessing that your label shape must be one dimensional like `(5000,)` you can see it by using `labels.shape`.
To make it two dimensional use this

```
labels = np.expand_dims(labels,axis=1)
```

2. **Second one: Units in last dense layer**

You have used number of units in last `dense` layer 2, so basically it is a multiclass classification behaving like binary classification. I recommend if you are doing binary classification then use 1 unit at last `dense` layer and activation other than `softmax`. If your dataset has 3 or more than 3 class then use `dense` layer with number of output class and `softmax` activation. But for such cases the labels should be `one hot encoded`.

3. **Third one: Change the loss function** 
If you are going to still use the 2 unit output for last dense layer. Change your loss function from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your TF version, but maybe you should use the fit_generator (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator) method instead of model.fit if your input is a generator.

Also check what previous answers mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wrong in

1. converting list of numpy array to single numpy array, you can use

   `data = np.stack( data, axis=0 )/255`

   or

   `data = np.concatenate( data, axis=0 )` # it will return shape (bath_size, dim_height * dim_width, channel) then reshape the data

   `data.reshape(bath_size, dim_height, dim_width, channel)`

   or

   `data = np.vstack(data)/255.0`

   [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array)
2. after using lb.fit_transform(labels) you no need to use to_categorical(labels)
3. It not clear what do you want, multi-label or multi-class? it's different. if you want to change to multi-label case, the binary_crossentropy is one of solution. but you will confuse in accuracy (default) as metric, it is wrong in multi-label, you can use accuracy calculation for multi-label classification. and don't use softmax in final activation output, please use sigmoid. Or if its multi-class change the loss to categorical_crossentropy if its label is one hot encoding, or to sparse_categorical_crossentropy if its label is number not one hot encoding.
4. if its binary image classification before, the output model must be 1 (1 or 0) not 2

hope this answer becomes your solution