# How to convert list of numpy arrays to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a sliding window for LSTM. For this I have:

```
x_train=[[]]
y_train = []

for i in range(10, len(train_data)):
  x_train.append(train_data[i-10:i])
  y_train.append(train_data[i,0])
```

The shape of `train_data` is (2730, 2), so I suppose `x_train` will be (2721, 10, 2).
After the loop `x_train` and `y_train` are **lists** of numpy arrays.
In tutorials it's enough to apply `np.asarray` or `np.array` to change it to numpy array. In my case it changes shape to (2721, ) and that's not really what I expected.
Probably, it's better to use numpy arrays and not lists.
But I wonder why in tutorials the way I do works and it doesn't for me. Maybe there is a small error or something in the code?

**P.S.** Sorry, I found an error by myself. It was `x_train=[[]]`, but it should be `x_train=[]`.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array) answer your question?

Comment: thank you, it's solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert list of numpy arrays into single numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array)

Comment: @Chris,its same link

Comment: @matanh yeah it's auto filled when I voted to close the question as duplicated, if you have the rep to vote to close that's probably better than posting the link directly.

Comment: Well np.asarray function solved the problem. My error was that i created a nested array x_train=[[]] instead of x_train=[] . So there is no need to concatenate np arrays. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. Actually in that situation it was a good solution to concatenate numpy arrays. Here I made an error creating a wrong type of list, so the fix is rather obvious, just to replace `x_train=[[]]` by `x_train=[]`.