# Adding Images to an array that gives back number of images and dimension of images in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image

How can I add these images which I have converted to a (95,95) array into an array that gives me the number of images I have (in my case 10) and the dimensions of those images (95,95)?
My desired output would be an array <10,95,95>.

This is my code so far, thank you! [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lxK5.jpg):

```
import cv2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# https://www.ocr2edit.com/convert-to-txt
x_train = "C:/Users/cuevas26/ae/crater_images_test"
categories = ["crater"]

#for category in categories:
path = x_train
for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    imgs = cv2.resize(img_array, (95, 95))
    plt.imshow(imgs, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

    print(type(imgs))
    print(imgs.shape)
```

Comment: Please add tried code with question avoid placing image, If I understand your question, add a `counter = 0` outside the `for` loop & increment it inside the loop after resizing `counter += 1`, so you will get the total processed image count. Finally append and the values inside a array like `output = [],width,height=95,95` `output.append(counter)` `output.append(width)` `output.append(height)`

Comment: I Use [this site](https://www.ocr2edit.com/convert-to-txt) for converting your image to text (code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may append the images to a list, and convert the final list into NumPy array using [numpy.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

- Start with an empty list:

  ```
   images_list = []
  ```
- In the loop, after `img = cv2.resize`, append the resized image to the list:

  ```
   images_list.append(img)
  ```
- After the end of the loop, convert the list into 3D NumPy array:

  ```
   images = np.stack(images_list, axis=0)
  ```

---

`images.shape` is `(10, 95, 95)`.
`images.shape[0]` is the number of images.
`images.shape[1:]` is the image dimensions `(95, 95)`.
Use `images[i]` for accessing the image in index `i`.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# https://www.ocr2edit.com/convert-to-txt
x_train = "C:/Users/cuevas26/ae/crater_images_test"

images_list = []  # List of images - start with an empty list

# For category in categories:
path = x_train
for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img_array, (95, 95))
    images_list.append(img)  # Append the new image into a list

# Convert the list to of 2D arrays into 3D NumPy array (the first index is the index of the image).
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516849/how-to-convert-list-of-numpy-arrays-into-single-numpy-array
images = np.stack(images_list, axis=0)

print(type(images))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(images.shape)  # (10, 95, 95)

n_images = images.shape[0]

# Show the images (using cv2.imshow instead of matplotlib)
for i in range(n_images):
    cv2.imshow('img', images[i])
    cv2.waitKey(1000)  # Wait 1 second

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```